# Populating random number by grouping

Tags: sql, oracle, random

I have following ***sample data***

```
ID  Category    Status  Seq Start DT    End DT
1   CAT 1   U   1   17-Feb-11   17-Feb-11
1   CAT 1   I   2   17-Feb-11   17-Feb-11
1   CAT 1   X   0   17-Feb-11   3-Mar-11
1   CAT 1   X   0   3-Mar-11    4-Mar-11
1   CAT 1   X   0   4-Mar-11    28-Jun-11
1   CAT 1   I   6   28-Jun-11   29-Jun-11
1   CAT 1   X   0   29-Jun-11   15-Jul-11
1   CAT 1   X   0   15-Jul-11   28-Jul-11
1   CAT 1   X   0   28-Jul-11   28-Jul-11
1   CAT 1   I   10  28-Jul-11   1-Aug-11
1   CAT 1   D   11  1-Aug-11    8-Aug-11
1   CAT 1   E   0   8-Aug-11    9-Aug-11
1   CAT 1   E   0   9-Aug-11    1-Sep-11
1   CAT 1   E   0   1-Sep-11    13-Sep-11
```

***Expected Output:-***

```
ID  Category    Status  Seq Start DT    End DT
1   CAT 1   U   1   17-Feb-11   17-Feb-11
1   CAT 1   I   2   17-Feb-11   17-Feb-11
1   CAT 1   X   0   17-Feb-11   3-Mar-11
1   CAT 1   X   0   3-Mar-11    4-Mar-11
1   CAT 1   X   0   4-Mar-11    28-Jun-11
1   CAT 1   I   6   28-Jun-11   29-Jun-11
1   CAT 1   X   ***0A***    29-Jun-11   15-Jul-11
1   CAT 1   X   ***0A***    15-Jul-11   28-Jul-11
1   CAT 1   X   ***0A***    28-Jul-11   28-Jul-11
1   CAT 1   I   10  28-Jul-11   1-Aug-11
1   CAT 1   D   11  1-Aug-11    8-Aug-11
1   CAT 1   E   0   8-Aug-11    9-Aug-11
1   CAT 1   E   0   9-Aug-11    1-Sep-11
1   CAT 1   E   0   1-Sep-11    13-Sep-11
```

The "seq" column is sql generated column, which is basically rownum. for the same set of values in the status column the "seq" values should remain same eg 0 in this case. but for the next set of same status values the "seq" value should be something different from the previous one eg 0A. for all other cases the seq value will be just rownum.
Thanks

Comment: The screenshot does not describe what is happening, nor what is supposed to happen.

Comment: Thanks for replying back. I used SQL (rownum) to generate SEQ column. When "status" is having same value then the "SEQ" will have some different value (other than rownum) eg. 0 in this case. But if the same group of values appears again for "status" then the "seq" column should have some different value eg 00. But in my case i am getting 0 for every GROUP of status values. Hope this will make sense.

Comment: @Harry, please edit your question and add the relevant information there. Also better provide some sample data and expected output, instead of attaching the picture.

Comment: Hi I updated my question, also updated the sample and expected data. Not sure how to insert sample and expected data in proper table format.

Comment: Please tell us more about why those three rows should have ***OA***.

Comment: Thanks for replying, well, with seq coloumn I want to differentiate  between the first set of X status and the second set of X status. so, it should have any other value than 0 as 0 is already assigned to the first set of X values.

Comment: How are ordered your rows? Without a proper `ORDER BY`  clause, rows are unordered, so there is not really such thing as the _"**first** set of value"_ or _"**second** set of values"_. As I suspect this might be complex, could you think of some [very minimal but executable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? BTW, when you reply to comments, try to ping the asker (using `@pseudo`. Otherwise there is little chance she even came back here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's enough to just get a separate value for all groups, you could use a `SUM() OVER()` clause to generate the group names. Here I assume that `ORDER BY "Start DT", "End DT", "Seq"` is enough to get the correct ordering of the rows, so you may want to tweak that if not correct.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT "ID", "Category", "Status", "Seq", "Start DT", "End DT", 
    SUM("Seq") OVER (ORDER BY "Start DT", "End DT", "Seq") "Seq2"
  FROM mytable
) 
SELECT "ID", "Category", "Status", 
  CASE WHEN "Seq"=0 
       THEN 'A' || CAST("Seq2" AS VARCHAR(32))
       ELSE CAST("Seq" AS VARCHAR(32)) 
       END "Seq",
  "Start DT", "End DT" 
FROM cte
```

Since the values we want to group have the value 0, the SUM will generate the same value for each row (since the sum does not change when we add 0), so we can use the sum to generate a group name.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/42aaa/1).

Comment: The query works perfect but the problem is if I have data like 
STATUS  START_DT END_DT 
E  03/FEB/12 08/FEB/12
E  08/FEB/12 13/JUL/12
I  13/JUL/12 31/JUL/12
I  31/JUL/12 28/AUG/12
E  28/AUG/12 06/SEP/12
E  06/SEP/12 10/DEC/12
The query will not generate the different SEQ for last two “E” statuses. It will assign the same SEQ as the first two “E” statuses because the SEQ will be 0 for both the “I” statuses and the sum won’t change in this case.
Hope this makes sense.
Thanks

Comment: @Harry Hm, could you update the SQLfiddle I built with that data? It's a bit hard to parse in comment format.

Comment: [Sample SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/59ef9/4) 
You will see that record 3,4,5 and 8,9 have the same status and seq. My requirement is different SEQ for these groups (one for 3,4,5 and one for 8,9)